# What is the best way to call callback in child scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page that loads some data by multiple http requests, then afterwards I have to do some logic in several directives inside of this page.
I'd like to ask, what is the best pratice for this kind of situations?
Right now I have a boolean flag, that indicates that content been loaded. The first idea was to use timeout in these directives to check each second if the content is loaded, and execute this logic if it does.
The second idea was to use the broadcasting. I like this idea, but since those directives has closure scopes, as far as I get, I have to broadcast on the $rootScope. And as far as I understand, this is not the best idea in the terms of productivity.
So please, let me know what is the best solution for this kind of task.

Comment: That depends on the hierarchy of the DOM. Are the directives encapsulated by common ancestor other than `$rootScope`? If they are all encapsulated in the same controller you could just do `$scope.$broadcast` which has the same effect but only to the children of the current scope.

Comment: Well the ancestor is the same - page controller's scope. But the child scopes could be pretty low in the hierarchy. Like page contains a directive, and this directive contains another directive, which will listen to this broadcast. That's why the question is, is it better to do broadcast on the page's scope, or emit on the rootScope?

Comment: `$emit` is probably the way to go because it only publishes to its subscribers. `$broadcast` has to go through every child scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$rootScope.emit() is the best approach for angular1. This is the built in pubsub pattern

$rootscope.emit() is not expensive as the broadcast method since the broadcast percolates down all the scopes

Just use emit in controller

```
$rootScope.$emit('topic');

in directive

$rootScope.$on('topic', function(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for this. Specifically it's `$q.all()` method

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when
>   all of the input promises are resolved.

The advantage is that is is "Angular native" so do not need to worry about synchronization with $scope etc

Comment: I don't understand your idea. I'm already using q.all() on the page's top level scope to find out when all the the data will be loaded and set the "loaded" flag to true. But how can this help me to execute some logic in multiple child directives? Sure, I could try to pass down all the promises using array, but I'm not sure that this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Aha.. I see. In that case use `$rootScope.$emit` as proposed by @Piyush.kapoor